# selecting particular month as default in calendar extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a start date and end date field. Both has seperate ajax calender extenders. Once we click on the end date calender control after selecting the start date one, I would like to show the same month corresponding to the start date in the end date calendar. How can we do that. I have tried adding javascript function onClientShown event of calender extender; but didnt work out.

The basic idea is that the user will be any ways selecting a date greater than start date in the endate text box.

Comment: What calendar are you using? Can you post a sample of your code and of what you did try to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just used  a js-debugger to see what properties and functions a `CalendarExtender` has on clientside. Two interesting things found, the `OnClientShown` event and the `set_visibleDate` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ApplyStartMonth(sender, args) {
        var calendarStart = $find('CalendarExtender1');
        sender.set_visibleDate(calendarStart._selectedDate);
        // the following is not needed here but good to know that they exist
        //sender.set_todaysDate(calendarStart._selectedDate);
        //sender.set_selectedDate(calendarStart._selectedDate);
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtStart" runat="server" Text="22.03.2012"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd.MM.yyyy" TargetControlID="TxtStart" /><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" Format="dd.MM.yyyy" 
   OnClientShown="ApplyStartMonth" TargetControlID="TxtEnd" />
```